# I need to round incorrectly to 2 significant figures

Tags: r, rounding

I'm working with an arcane set of rounding rules that are similar to those implemented in base R only wrong. I need to round values to 2 significant figures using the "round to even" rule when the third digit is 5, but I need all of the digits to the right of the 5 to be ignored when making this determination. Here is a minimal example.

What R does:

```
> signif(2059, 2)
[1] 2100
```

Behavior I want:

```
> signif(2059, 2)
[1] 2000
```

I tried to think of ways to do this with the functions I'm aware of, but came up blank. Something with str_sub might work to replace every digit after the 5 with a 0, but not all the numbers I'm working with have the same number of digits and I'm not sure how to deal with that when it comes to the replacement part of the function.

Edit: here is an expanded example, with the differences marked with an asterisk.

What R does:

```
x <- c(25, 211, 215, 216, 2250, 2251, 2350, 2359, 24500, 24563)
signif(x, 2)
 [1]    25   210   220   220  2200  2300  2400  2400 24000 25000
```

What I want:

```
x <- c(25, 211, 215, 216, 2250, 2251, 2350, 2359, 24500, 24563)
signif(x, 2)
 [1]    25   210   220   220  2200  *2200  2400  2400 24000 *24000
```

Comment: What are the expected results for `2049` and `2069`? And if *"not all the numbers I'm working with have the same number of digits"*  you should post a more complete input example with corresponding output.

Comment: This is an interesting question - it would be a better question if you gave more than 1 sample input. Could you give a vector `x` with, say, 10 test cases and the expected result? Like, if the input is `x = c(20, 25, 249, 250, 251, 259, 2490, 2501, 2550, 2559, 25555)`, what would you want the output to be rounding to 2 and 3 digits?

Comment: I added an expanded example to my question.

Comment: It comes from Standard Methods for the Examination of Dairy Products, 17 ed., §6.020 Standard Plate Count Method (Class O). The raw result of this test is more or less limited to the numbers 0-250. Because of this, the rule for rounding, as stated in the method, says: "When the third digit is 5, round up if the second digit is odd and round down when the second digit is even." It doesn't mention digits beyond 3 because there shouldn't be any. I've been instructed to apply this rule beyond this test to other tests that produce results of more than 3 digits, where it makes things wrong and weird

Comment: @SamuelReichler  Don't ya just love it when a PHB says to use a demonstrably wrong algo?  :-( .  Personally I'd say "yes boss" and then do proper rounding anyway.  Nobody will ever know.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use `%/%` and `log10` to cut of the right numbers?

```
x <- c(25, 211, 215, 216, 2250, 2251, 2350, 2359, 24500, 24563, 0)

signifIncorect <- function(x, digits = 2) {
  n <- ceiling(log10(abs(x)))
  y <- 10^(n - 1 - digits)
  replace(round(x %/% y * y, digits - n), x==0, 0)
}
signifIncorect(x, 2)
# [1]    25   210   220   220  2200  2200  2400  2400 24000 24000     0
```

Comment: This is brilliant and does what I want, except for it returns 'NaN' when there are zeros in the dataset. I can deal with that, though.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Now it should work also for 0. Hope there are only positive integer values?

Comment: Yes, only positive values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing TheWrongThing(TM).  First of all,  2059 rounded to two engineering places is 2100.  2100 is **not** an odd number.  And for that matter,  2059 is not a number whose least significant digit is "5" .  You seem to desire some strange mixture of rounding and truncation, and I fail to see the mathematical utility of doing so.

Keep in mind how `signif` works:

Quoting from the man page,

> Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard (see also ‘IEEE
> 754’) is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’. Therefore
> round(0.5) is 0 and round(-1.5) is -2. However, this is dependent on
> OS services and on representation error (since e.g. 0.15 is not
> represented exactly, the rounding rule applies to the represented
> number and not to the printed number, and so round(0.15, 1) could be
> either 0.1 or 0.2).

Further, the man page explicitly points out that

> signif(x, dig) is the same as round(x, dig - ceiling(log10(abs(x))))

Comment: I think the OP started by saying that **they know the rounding rule they are implementing is wrong** - so telling them it's wrong might not be helpful ...

Comment: @BenBolker maybe; my interpretation is that they are trying to produce a result that is explicitly incorrect.